# UIButton titleLabel not vertically centered when using minimumScaleFactor

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton and the text is centered within the button normally until the text string gets longer and it starts to scale down the size of the text. Then the text seems to stick to the bottom of the textField instead of staying centered in the button.

```
self.titleBtn.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.titleBtn.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .2;

[self.descriptionBtn setTitle:@"T" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
//works normally
```

but

```
[self.descriptionBtn setTitle:@"This a longer title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//is vertically lower than center
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As noted [here](https://twitter.com/TT_Kilew/status/626351381960617984) :)
You need to user `baselineAdjustment` propery of the UILabel
`label.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters`

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 3**

```
label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```

For **Button**

```
button.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```